# Filter Rows - Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, rowfilter

We are Getting inputs from two different tables and passing it to the Filter rows.
But we are getting the below error.
[image]

The DATE_ADDED Table has only one column DATE_ADDED and similarly the TODAYS_DATE Table  has a single column TODAYS_DATE .
The condition given in the Filter is DATE_ADDED < TODAYS_DATE .
The transaformation is
[image]

Can someone tell, where I am doing the mistake

Comment: if you preview the dummy-step (without filter-step) or the "DATE_ADDED"-input it works? I don't think appending two streams with different names in the dummy step can work?! I would check if there is really data coming from "DATE_ADDED". It dowesn't look like it and in the end that's what the error-message says ...

Answer (score 0):

It won't work like this. You expect a join of two streams (like SQL JOIN of two tables) but actually you will have a union (like SQL UNION).

When two streams are intersected on a step they must have identical columns - names, order and types - and the result will be the union of both streams with the same structure as origins.

When you intersect streams with different structures - different column names in your case - you will have unpredictable column names and actually only one column - nothing to compare with.

To do what you need use the Merge Join step (do not forget to sort streams on the joining key)

Answer (score 0):

Both the column names and types should be identical if you wanna merge the columns in single step, right click on both steps and click **output fields** to verify the datatypes.

if datatype issues arrives OR you want to rename the columns, you can place **select** step(for each table steps) after table steps and select the **DATE Type**(in your case)in the **Meta-data** tab, and **rename** the fields as well.

Hope this helps... :)